# Read session written in webroot in cakephp 2 pages controller

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a script located in app/webroot/myscript/antispam.php

the code is just like

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['my_anti_spam'] = 'myantispam';
```

but then when I tried read it from pagescontroller,

```
@session_start();
debug($_SESSION);
```

It does not have any session.

What should I do? How can I read a session which written on webroot folder from controller?

Comment: check if session_start() called at pagescontroller

Comment: @JasonOOO yes, it has. check my updated code

Comment: try this: `if(session_start()){ $_SESSION['my_anti_spam'] = 'myantispam';} else echo 'session notstarted'`

Comment: @JasonOOO I put that at antispam.php, still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call session start in Cake, it will call it automatically.

In your antispam script, you will need something like this:

```
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
session_save_path(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DS . 'tmp' . DS . 'sessions');

session_name('CAKEPHP');

session_start();
```

This assumes that you are storing sessions in the app/tmp/sessions directory, ie you have something like this in your app/Config/core.php file:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake',
    'timeout' => 6 * 60,    // Timeout in minutes
    'autoRegenerate' => false,
    'ini' => array(
      'session.cookie_secure' => false
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to set session in webroot index file? If you want to use this session all over the project, please add session in appController beforeFilter method.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this on your controller or view:

```
$this->Session->write('my_anti_spam', 'myantispam');
```

Then you can read the session by:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->read("my_anti_spam");?>
```

You can destroy the session by:

```
$this->Session->delete('my_anti_spam');
```